# C Bubble trouble

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

I'm having some issue building a bubble in C. I'm trying to simply get it to spit out the array before, during, and after being sorted out, and I'm having issues.
It's worthwhile to mention this would be my first program in C.
The following is what I'm working on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9
void printValues();
void sort();
void swap(int*, int*);

int values[] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};

int main(void){
        printf("Before: \n");
        printValues();
        sort();
        printf("After: \n");
        printValues();

        return(0);
}

void printValues(){
        int i;
        printf(" List before arranging: \n[");
        for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
                printf(" %d "values[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
}

void sort(){
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                for (j = 0; j< 9-i; j++){
                        if (values[j] < values[j+1]){
                                swap((values + j), (values + j +1));
                        }
                }
        }
}


void swap(int x, int y){
        int temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
}
```

Of course, I ran it before this and cleared some mistakes I understood from my time in python3. However, now I recieve these.

```
bubble.c:29:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘values’
   printf(" %d "values[i]);
                ^
bubble.c: In function ‘sort’:
bubble.c:39:20: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
     swap(values[j]*, values[j+1]*);
                    ^
bubble.c:39:34: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
     swap(values[j]*, values[j+1]*);
                                  ^
bubble.c: At top level:
bubble.c:45:6: error: conflicting types for ‘swap’
 void swap(int x, int y){
      ^
bubble.c:11:6: note: previous declaration of ‘swap’ was here
 void swap(int*, int*);
      ^
bubble.c: In function ‘swap’:
bubble.c:46:13: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  int temp = *x;
             ^
bubble.c:47:2: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  *x = *y;
  ^
bubble.c:47:7: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  *x = *y;
       ^
bubble.c:48:2: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  *y = temp;
  ^
```

I'm trying to get the hang of pointers and can't find help for this that I have left. Any help?

Comment: Your code is filled with typos. That's what most of the messages are about. The first warning is due to the fact that `main` should be declared `int main(void)`. Note that each message contains a line number and column number, e.g. `bubble.c:48:2` means that the problem is on line 48 at column 2.

Comment: Resolved it. Apoligies.

Comment: Did you resolve all of the problems, or just the ones changed in the edit?

Comment: the edit. I've tried looking up my issues related to the swap and have had little success in the past few hours. Changed the post to reflect the changes.

Comment: It would be a good idea to recompile, and post the updated error messages. That's the standard workflow with C. Fix a few errors, then recompile and see what errors remain.

Comment: That's what I've done, and adjusted above.

Comment: Nope, you simply removed the first warning. The error messages remaining no longer match the code in the question.

Comment: gave it another go, guess I didn't hit enter?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed arrays and pointer together because you have written values[j]* instead of (values + j ) and you have pass integer instead of inn pointer

Comment: How would I rewrite it?